# Condition based Game Matching - Game centre iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, game-center

I am using game centre for my game for the multiplayer. Player can join game in two ways

1. "Game creator" who put some puzzle and
2. "Challenge acceptor" who want to solve the puzzle.

"Game creator" will decide the winner.

But I am stuck on the issue that is can we use game centre like this 
Like : I am putting my puzzle on and waiting for random players to join, but How come Game centre will decide that only "challenge acceptors" joins the game ?

If anybody knows please help me out. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use player attributes. From the [Game Center Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/MatchmakingwithGameCenter/MatchmakingwithGameCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH12-SW12):

> A player attribute allows a player to pick the role he or she wants to
>   play within a match. With player attributes, each player can choose a
>   specific role and Game Center finds a proper mix of players to ensure
>   that all of the roles are filled.

To use player attributes, set the `playerAttributes` property of the `GKMatchRequest` before matchmaking. The game creator could use `playerAttributes` 0xFFFF0000, and the challenge acceptor could use `playerAttributes` 0x0000FFFF. The key is that the bitwise OR of the two values be 0xFFFFFFFF:

> If Game Center sees a nonzero player attribute in the match request,
>   it adds players to the match intelligently so that all of the players,
>   when combined using a logical [sic] OR operation, have a complete mask of
>   FFFFFFFFh.

Comment: Thanks jonahb, You saved hell of time for me. Thanks again